# How to get the X and Y coordinates of the mouse click in percentage using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I went searching and found the following code and wanted to know how to convert it to work in reactjs

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(s);

// 4. Then paste this
var oldx = 0, oldy = 0;

var newImg = $('img').attr('src');

$('img').detach();

$('body').append('<img src="' + newImg + '" style="margin:0; height:100vh; width:auto">');

$('img').off( "click" ).click(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var x = Math.floor((e.pageX - offset.left) / $(this).width() * 10000)/100;
  var y = Math.floor((e.pageY - offset.top) / $(this).height() * 10000)/100;

  console.log(x, y, x - oldx, y - oldy);
  oldx = x; oldy = y;
});

// 5. Click on the points you're interested. You'll get x,y coordinates in percentage of the image
// and dx and dy from the previous clicked point.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'


class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.img = React.createRef();  
    }

    oldx= 0; oldy = 0;

    imageClick = (e) => {
        var offset = this.img.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = Math.floor((e.pageX - offset.left) / offset.width * 10000)/100;
        var y = Math.floor((e.pageY - offset.top) / offset.height * 10000)/100;
        console.log(x, y, x - this.oldx, y - this.oldy);
        this.oldx = x; this.oldy = y;
    }
    

    render(){
        return <img onClick={this.imageClick} ref={this.img} src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style={{margin:0, height:"100vh", width:"auto"}}></img>
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: I'm using React Function Component, it doesn't allow me to do it that way! **const Create: React.FC = () => {}**